# Can't Delete Image File while using TinyMCE

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, tinymce, asyncfileupload

I am using TinyMCE AND AsyncFileUpload AND an Update Panel
After Uploading , I cannot delete the Images while Adding them to tinymce content

because it is being used by another process.

lock (this) 
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(_FILE_HANDLER_))
                        {

```
                        File.Delete(_FILE_HANDLER_);
                    }
                }
```

Do I have to Dispose TinyMce ::

Like This :

```
 tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
```

Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the upload process is still holding onto the image.

Comment: i tried 
AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
...
its still the same ..